# Questions about using createAysncThunk

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I am new to redux and redux toolkit. I am reading this tutorial from redux toolkit official document. https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk. This is an example it provides

```js
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice, unwrapResult } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { userAPI } from './userAPI'

const fetchUserById = createAsyncThunk(
  'users/fetchByIdStatus',
  async (userId, { getState, requestId }) => {
    const { currentRequestId, loading } = getState().users
    if (loading !== 'pending' || requestId !== currentRequestId) {
      return
    }
    const response = await userAPI.fetchById(userId)
    return response.data
  }
)

const usersSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'users',
  initialState: {
    entities: [],
    loading: 'idle',
    currentRequestId: undefined,
    error: null
  },
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: {
    [fetchUserById.pending]: (state, action) => {
      if (state.loading === 'idle') {
        state.loading = 'pending'
        state.currentRequestId = action.meta.requestId
      }
    },
    [fetchUserById.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      const { requestId } = action.meta
      if (state.loading === 'pending' && state.currentRequestId === requestId) {
        state.loading = 'idle'
        state.entities.push(action.payload)
        state.currentRequestId = undefined
      }
    },
    [fetchUserById.rejected]: (state, action) => {
      const { requestId } = action.meta
      if (state.loading === 'pending' && state.currentRequestId === requestId) {
        state.loading = 'idle'
        state.error = action.error
        state.currentRequestId = undefined
      }
    }
  }
})

const UsersComponent = () => {
  const { users, loading, error } = useSelector(state => state.users)
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const fetchOneUser = async userId => {
    try {
      const resultAction = await dispatch(fetchUserById(userId))
      const user = unwrapResult(resultAction)
      showToast('success', `Fetched ${user.name}`)
    } catch (err) {
      showToast('error', `Fetch failed: ${err.message}`)
    }
  }

  // render UI here
}
```

my question is, since we have handled the case where the promise rejects in the lifecycle action creator i.e.

```js
[fetchUserById.rejected]: (state, action) => {
      const { requestId } = action.meta
      if (state.loading === 'pending' && state.currentRequestId === requestId) {
        state.loading = 'idle'
        state.error = action.error
        state.currentRequestId = undefined
      }
    }
```

Then why is that, in `UsersComponent`, we still need to try and catch the error thrown by the dispatch.Can't we tell if the request failed or not from the `error` state? To be clearer, what about I write the  `UsersComponent` this following way:

```js
const UsersComponent = () => {
  const { users, loading, error } = useSelector(state => state.users)
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchUserById(userId))
  },[dispatch])

  if(error) {
    showToast('error', `Fetch failed: ${error.message}`)
  } else if(loading) {
    showToast('loading')
  } else {
    showToast('success', `Fetched ${user.name}`)
  }

  // render UI here
}
```

Additionally, I wonder when the `fetchUserById.rejected` would be dispatched? According to the doc, `createAsyncThunk` will always return a resolved promise. If we hit this condition in the callback of `createAsyncThunk`

```js
if (loading !== 'pending' || requestId !== currentRequestId) {
      return
    }
```

then the lifecycle action gets dispatched would be `fulfilled` right? What does it take for the `rejected` lifecyle action gets dispatched? Only when an exception is thrown inside of the callback?

My last question is, if I'd like to check if the data I got back is of the right shape, for example, I want to make sure if has a property called `data` on it. How can I achieve that? If I rewrite the callback in `createAsyncThunk` to be

```js
const fetchUserById = createAsyncThunk(
  'users/fetchByIdStatus',
  async (userId, { getState, requestId }) => {
    const { currentRequestId, loading } = getState().users
    if (loading !== 'pending' || requestId !== currentRequestId) {
      return
    }
    const response = await userAPI.fetchById(userId)
    if(!response.data) throw new Error('No data')
    return response.data
  }
)
```

will the `rejected` lifecycle action gets dispatched when there is actually no `data` property on the `response`?

Comment: Please focus on a single question per post, for your first question: your example won't work because you dispatch an `asyncThunk`, it returns a promise, you can easily check your code.

Comment: @DennisVash it actually WORKS. I know it returns a promise. but by dispatching that `asyncThunk`, the thunk will dispatch the pending action and if the promise resolved successfully, dispatch the fulfilled action with the promise value as action.payload.

Comment: So what is the problem? If it work thats ok

Comment: @DennisVash The problem is stated in the question in the post. if you don't want to answer why can't you just ignore this question

Answer (score 1):

As for the first part of your question:
Yes, you could do that on a subsequent render.
But if you just write

```
  if(error) {
    showToast('error', `Fetch failed: ${error.message}`)
  } else if(loading) {
    showToast('loading')
  } else {
    showToast('success', `Fetched ${user.name}`)
  }
```

that would show a toast on *every* subsequent render of that component. And in React, that component will re-render every time a parent is rendered, so you will probably see a lot of Toasts.

You can of course also use `useEfect` for that and then do it that way, if you like that better. That's just a style thing, some people like one way better, some the other.

A `rejected` action would for example be dispatched when `userAPI.fetchById` would throw an error, maybe due to network problems.

If just `return`  is called, it will actually return `undefined` and lead to a fulfilled action with `undefined` as payload.